# Why wasn't Neo's monitor connected to anything?

Tags: the-matrix

When Neo is sitting in his cubicle after being reamed out by the boss for being late to work, his monitor is off and he doesn't appear to be working - in fact, his monitor doesn't appear to even be connected to a computer. Why is this? Were the filmmakers just being cheap and hoping that no one would notice, or is there some other reason? Is it possible that there's some kind of symbolism here?

Comment: there are a ton of bloopers in this movie, so it could be that. or someone somewhere has a theory justifying this blooper, probably about being "disconnected" from reality and being set free

Comment: He didn't get a chance to turn on his computer, so it's still turned off from yesterday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we later discover in the movie, you can alter the laws of nature because the world we are living is not exactly real. So the ones communicating with Neo know how to do this.

I think that's what the filmmakers are trying to say here. Someone who does not obey to the physical laws is trying to communicate with Neo. So I guess this was not them being cheap rather than trying to stress this 'supernatural' element of the one behind the messages.

Comment: ...........or someone from props dept got their head chewed off later that day. Not being sarcastic. People make mistakes.